# Google map multiple polygons/colors zooming turn black/wrong color

Tags: google-maps, colors, polygon

The map has a couple of polygons with different colors (yellow -> red). The polygons are rendered, it looks fine, aside from a partialy black polygon on the right:

[image]

Then when I zoom a bit, the colors get messed up. Also one gets multiple colors? (blue arrow):

[image]

What is going on?

[image]

This is how the polygons are created. The fillColor 'color' is a hex '#FF0000'. I've tried setting a different zIndex for each of them, incremental.

```
    let coordinates: any[] = [];
    for (let r = 0; r < polygon.length; r++) {
      coordinates.push(polygon[r]);
      bounds.extend(polygon[r])
    }
    // Construct the polygon

    let newPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: coordinates,
      strokeColor: '#888888',
      strokeOpacity: 0.0,
      strokeWeight: 1,
      fillColor: color,
      fillOpacity: 1,
      clickable: true,
      zIndex: 1,
      editable: false
    });

    newPolygon.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, including sample data.